# Set a custom message after saving a new node

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-node-hook

Im trying to set a custom message that gets shown to users after they submit a new node.  This message is going replace the standard '@type %title has been created.'

I've tried using hook_nodeapi with $op of 'insert' but no matter how I try and change module weights, my custom message always appears first before the core drupal message.

This wont work, as I need to call drupal_get_messages() to remove the orginal message before sending my own custom one.

This workflow is driving me insane, can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [node_form_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.pages.inc/function/node_form_submit/6) function. Notice that it does a `node_save($node);` before `drupal_set_message(t('@type %title has been created.', $t_args));`.

If you then check out [node_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_save/6), you'll see that's where the 'insert' $op gets called. So, the 'insert' operation for hook_nodeapi gets called before the message you're hoping to change gets output.

You can find [some workarounds described in this issue queue comment](http://drupal.org/node/699260#comment-2535740). You may also want to check out the [Custom Submit Messages module](http://drupal.org/project/csm), which is where that issue queue thread originates.

In case it might help, in the past, I've sometimes resorted to writing a mini-module that implements hook_nodeapi, to find out just how the hooks are getting fired:

```
function mymodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  switch ($op) {
    dpm('hook_nodeapi '. $op .' fired.');
  }
}
```